# AWS Lightsail WHM Updated Autodiscovery to ON and now nothing loads

Tags: amazon-web-services, whm, amazon-lightsail, autodiscovery

Can anyone help diagnose what I did. I was trying to enable autodiscovery and now WHM/Cpanel/website will not resolve. I can still access via SSH.

All I did was enable the autodiscovery option and click save. This is the message afterwards.

```
Updating tweak settings...

Your changes have been saved.

Restarting cPanel daemons...done.

Updating your system to reflect any changes...
Updating “Thunderbird and Outlook autodiscover and autoconfig support (enables service subdomain and SRV record creation)” from “Off” to “On”.
“Thunderbird and Outlook autodiscover and autoconfig support (enables service subdomain and SRV record creation)” was updated.
Processing post action for Thunderbird and Outlook autodiscover and autoconfig support (enables service subdomain and SRV record creation):
Creating service subdomain DNS entries in background. This process can take several minutes to complete.
“Thunderbird and Outlook autodiscover and autoconfig support (enables service subdomain and SRV record creation)” was updated.
Done.
```

Now the website is down, whm/cpanel is down, and email bouncing. Any ideas??

Hosted on AWS Lightsail, using GoDaddy nameservers and dns.

I feel like it somehow turned on internal dns maybe?